# "events in mind"

Tags: meaning-in-context

When talking about scheduled events or appointments can we use the following:

> A. I am calling from Dr. A' office; I just wanted to let you know that you have an appointment tomorrow at 2:00 PM.
>
> B. Yea, I have that **in mind**.  [to mean like I already know about it and have made my arrangements]

Answer (score 2):

To have in mind is to be aware.

"I am aware of it."

Answer (score 1):

Not really. *To have something in mind* means you're thinking about it and haven't decided on a relevant course of action. The normal response would be something like *I hadn't forgotten, but thank you for reminding me.*

Comment: Your definition of the phrase seems wrong and certainly is not the usage I am familiar with.  For example,  dictionary.cambridge.org says of *[have something in mind](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/have-something-in-mind)*, "to have a plan or intention"; it says nothing about "haven't decided".

Comment: @jwpat7: Having a plan or an intention doesn't necessarily imply its implementation. As always, meaning depends on context.

Comment: @jwpat7: That definition is really a stretch from *"Have it in mind [**to** do something]"*. But in fact *no* variants of "in mind" would normally be used in OP's particular context - except perhaps if speaker A had continued with *"so don't let your preceding meeting over lunch drag on"*, in which case B might say *"I'll **bear** that in mind"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, while I agree with your comment that Barrie's definition is quite a stretch, I don't agree with the rest of your comment.  To my understanding, OP's usage is not unusual.

Comment: @jwpat7: You misunderstand me. I meant *your* definition was a stretch. Barrie's is more often ***bear** something in mind* - but so far as I'm concerned, OP's *"I have that in mind"* sounds odd in his context. In fact, I find it hard to imagine his exact words suiting *any* context. The closest I can get is *I have that in mind **too*** - said if someone just criticised your plan because they mistakenly thought it didn't cover some problem which you *have* in fact taken account of.

Comment: @BarrieEngland- Why 'I hadn't'? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Noah: Because the state of my not having forgotten preceded the reminder. 'I haven't forgotten' is also possible, but describes my state at the time of speaking.

Comment: @Barrie, Noah: Also simply because A said *"I just **wanted** to let you know"*, rather than *"I just **want** to..."*

Answer (score 1):

You might simply say yes, I have it *on my calendar*.